# Next tab shortcut not working with right side keys

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome, shortcut, tabs

I often navigate my many many open Chrome tabs using shortcuts for 'goto left tab' and 'goto right tab' using cmd + alt + left/right.

I'm using an apple keyboard and this works fine using the alt + cmd keys on the left of the space bar, but using the ones on the right (beside the arrow keys) doesn't work for the *right* tab (left works fine).

This is a minor annoyance but I find myself doing this one-handed while trying to multi-task and frankly it's not possible to do at the moment until I can fix the right tab issue.

This combination works fine in other applications, so I don't know what's going on with Chrome..

PS using an Apple external keyboard (A1242).

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked to see your cmd and alt keys on the right work in other applications?

Comment: Yes, they work fine in the other apps I've checked i.e. Atom.